# object has no find method when searching for distinct '_id'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to return all the '_id' values of documents using the following Schema:

```
var QuestionSchema = new Schema ({
    author: { type: String },
    title: { type: String },
    subject: { type: String },
    topic: { type: String },
    question: { type: String }, 
    correct_ans: { type: Number },
    explanation: { type: String },
    answers: [ String ],
    answer_stats: [ Number ], 
    tags: [ String ],
    publish: { type: Boolean }
});
```

However, when I run the following code:

```
var Question = mongoose.model('Question', Question, 'Question');
var question = new Question();
question.find().distinct( '_id' , function(err,questions){
    // Some code
});
```

I get the following error:

```
[TypeError: Object { _id: 54cf53aec22cbf242b9cde43,
  tags: [],
  answer_stats: [],
  answers: [] } has no method 'find']
```

It is only referring to the arrays in the Schema but I'm not searching them. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try use Question.find() without new

Comment: nice. i actually have several find functions in my code but no idea why I used a new in this case... thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.find()` is a static method of `Mongoose.Model` class, but you're calling not existing instance method instead. Here is a correct example:

```
var Question = mongoose.model('Question', Question, 'Question');
Question.find().distinct( '_id' , function(err,questions){
  // Some code
});
```

Please, see [Mongoose Queries Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) and [Mongoose API Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) for more info.